# Is this a good design for Java and C/D to communicate?

Tags: java, communication, d

I have a java program where certain parts are computationally intensive.
I wish to make that part (which essentially generates an image according to some text data) in C/D.
(Multiple instances of the C program might be running at the same time).

Now, I want to be able to track the progress of the C/D program, so the java code
needs to read the status (progess, errors) of the C/D program somehow.

My idea is to use the environment variables in the OS, to store the status, "TIME_LEFT=2h10m42s" sort of. 
Questions:

Is this a good idea, or is there something really bad about this design?
Are there some alternatives, (using sockets, stdin/stdout, other)?

EDIT: The Java works as a front-end, so the C/D code should *NOT* include anything specifically written for Java. The C/D code is essentially a stand-alone program, Java (or other) provides with GUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use environment variables for this, as you cannot communicate environment variables to another program by other than setting it before you start a new process. So you can't run a C program that changes environment variables that your parent java program can see.

Write line based status to stdout in your C (or D) program rather and read it in your java program.

Comment: Thanks, it seems rather straightforward to solve it with stdin/stdout.

Answer (score 2):

Using environment variables is a bad idea. Environment variables are inherited by new running processes. They aren't register-type variables that you can just pump and access from any process, so to speak :) You could use JNI and keep checking the time remaining in MS on the Java side, or have the C/D code poll the Java code with the time remaining in its loop (I prefer the other way, however).

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do the other way around .From Java to poll the status of execution.On each 5 seconds to call via JNI the status (progress) of the heavy execution.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Chris Dennett that this is a bad idea. I would avoid JNI - it is a terrific way to introduce subtle bugs that crash your JVM.

I would implement this by creating a C/D HTTP server running on the local host. The server accepts a POST request to /image/ to start creating the image, a long running process. That POST request returns immediately with a token. I would then GET /image/token which would return either the progress information or the image, depending on if it is done or not. Your Java process can then poll the GET /image/token URL.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using environment variable use JNA. It is easier than JNI and reliable method to communicate with the program. Another approach is you use Message Queue like [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/) for which C API also available and this is open source. It will decouple the application.